# How can i modify the json response i get to make it look like this before saving to local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, local-storage

I am getting a json response that looks like this :

```
{
    "+143500000": {
        "inbox": "active",

            "Messages": [{
                "id": "sms001",
                "Sender": "Tom",
                "Text": "hello world"
        }, {
            "id": "sms002",
                "Sender": "Jones",
                "Text": "bye world"
        }]

    }
}
```

I want to save this response to local storage but it needs to look like this

```
{
    "+143500000": {
        "inbox": "active",

            "Messages": {
            "sms001": {
                "Sender": "Tom",
                "Text": "hello world"
        },

            "sms002": {
                "Sender": "Jones",
                "Text": "bye world"
        }}

    }
}
```

How can i modify the response i get to make it look like that. I am a beginner at javascript. Your help would be greatly appreciated. Would love a sample in javascript or jquery to do this .

Thanks

Comment: What you want to save is not a valid json.

Comment: i may have made a mistake in putting the sample. But i hope you get the idea of what i want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic should be very easy to follow. Note that your starting json has `Messages` as an array, but you are requesting that it have named properties, so it must be turned into an object.

```
var data = {
  "+143500000": {
    "inbox": "active",
    "Messages": [
      {
        "id":"sms001",
        "Sender":"Tom",
        "Text": "hello world"
      },
      {
        "id":"sms002",
        "Sender":"Jones",
        "Text": "bye world"
      }
    ]
  }
};

var messages = {};
for (var i=0; i<data["+143500000"].Messages.length; ++i) {
  var item = data["+143500000"].Messages[i];
  messages[item.id] = item;
  delete messages[item.id].id;
}

data["+143500000"].Messages = messages;
console.log(data);

data = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(data);

localStorage.myJson = data;
console.log(localStorage.myJson);

var retrievedData = localStorage.myJson;
console.log(retrievedData);
```

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/OvOgERa/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

```
// if your value is in `a`, then:
for (k in a)
  if (a.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    hash = {};
    a[k].Messages.forEach(function(m) {
      hash[m.id] = m;
      delete m.id;
    });
  a[k].Messages = hash;
}
```